# how to make a custom and reusable table component in typescript react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i want to make a component of table which is reusable for every function
i am facing issue regrading columns and rows
how can i pass every time different data and columns for every table ?

currently i have created component for each table that's not i want to do
if i have the similar table how can i pass different data and columns to another ?

```
<Table
          className="v-table m-table"
          //   rowClassName={(record, index) => record.type}
          scroll={{ x: "max-content", y: 600 }}
          columns={mColumns}
          dataSource={mData}
          pagination={{
            className: "list-pagination",
            total: 85,

            defaultPageSize: 10,
            defaultCurrent: 1,
          }}
          expandable={{
            expandedRowRender,

            rowExpandable: (record) => record.name !== "Not Expandable",
            expandIcon: ({ expanded, onExpand, record }) =>
              expanded ? (
                <div className="icon-wrapper">
                  <i
                    className="icon-table-arrow-down"
                    style={{
                      fontSize: "9px",
                      width: "16px",
                      cursor: "pointer",
                    }}
                    onClick={(e) => onExpand(record, e)}
                  />
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="icon-wrapper">
                  <i
                    className="icon-table-arrow-right"
                    style={{ width: "16px", cursor: "pointer" }}
                    onClick={(e) => onExpand(record, e)}
                  />
                </div>
              ),
          }}
        />
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you want to "factor" out as it seems the `Table` component is already effectively the component you want, right? I guess you could abstract the "static" props away and factor it into something like `const MyTable = ({ columns, data }) => <Table ...... passed and static props ...... />)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question... why you not simply try:

```
const MyTable = ({missionColumns, missionData}) => {
     return <Table
          className="vmsb-table mission-table"
          //   rowClassName={(record, index) => record.type}
          scroll={{ x: "max-content", y: 600 }}
          columns={missionColumns}
          dataSource={missionData}
          ...etc...
     </Table>
}
```

Usage:

```
<MyTable missionColumns={yourcolumns} missionData={yourdata} />
```

**Regarding your second question**, you can pass in the same way a style attribute, es:

```
const YourComponent = ({displayValue}) => {
    return <div style={{display:displayValue}} />
}
```

usage:

```
<YourComponent displayValue="none" />
```

**or if you want to pass the entire style:**

```
const YourComponent = ({style}) => {
    return <div style={{...style}} />
}
```

usage:

```
<YourComponent style={{display:'none', margin:'4px' etc...}} />
```

Comment: in this where you pass "yourcolumns" , i have to define all the keys and same for "yourdata" for all data in the form of array ?

Comment: Yes, this depend on the "Table" library you are using, that is https://ant.design/components/table/

Comment: thank you . i have another question , how can i pas style attribute like
style={{display:{display}}}
usage
display="none"
i have tried this but didn't work can you help me with this ?

Comment: I've edited mi answers with an example for this :-)

Comment: thanks it worked !! can you please help me in this also ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70108711/how-can-i-pass-and-use-expandable-attribute-in-typescript-react-component-and-re